# $lookup to return unmatched items from other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I always thought that `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` would allow a `$lookup` on a record that does not exist and still return the main result.

Unfortunately in this case I only get data from AAA - I would like data from both AAA and BBB.

**property table**

```
{
    _id: "AAA",
    name: "Property AAA"
},
{
    _id: "BBB",
    name: "Property BBB"
}
```

**hotdeal table**

```
{
    _id: "001",
    property: "AAA",
    active: true,
    text: "very good deal"
}
```

**Aggregate**

```
db.property.aggregate([
{ $match: {} },
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "hotdeal",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "property",
        as: "hotdeals"
    }
},
{ 
    $unwind: { 
        path: "$hotdeals", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, 
{                                                   
    $match: {                                       
        "hotdeals.active": true
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id : 0,
        name : 1,
        "text" : "$hotdeals.text"
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Umm. No. Misread your question at first. It is not possible for `$lookup` to return information from another collection that simply does not match. You can instead perform the `$lookup` the other way around. Thus joining the "hotdeal" to the "property".

Comment: @NeilLunn how would you go about joining hotdeal to the property?

Comment: `db.hotdeal.aggregate([{ "$lookup": { "from": "property", "localField": "property", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "properties" } }])` Does this really need a question? I thought you would simply realize the silly mistake.

Comment: @NeilLunn ahh okie - I considered that already but one property can have several hotdeals also property is hooked up on a lot of other $lookups, I just didnt show them in order to make the example more simple.  It actually works fine as long as I dont do the $match on hotdeal. If I stick to only doing the lookup, then preserveNullAndEmptyArrays works fine.